# Localize App Title for Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, localization, windows-phone

I try to localize my app title for a windows phone 8 app. I used following documentation from microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx#Loc_Download

I also created mui files for each language (de-DE, en-US, en-GB). On the root folder of my windows phone 8 project I add these files:

- AppResLib.dll
- AppResLib.dll.0407.mui
- AppResLib.dll.0409.mui
- AppResLib.dll.0809.mui

For each file I set the built action to content.

When I start the app and change the language of my phone, always the default language app title is shown. When I upload my xap file to a beta app in marktplace I get following validation errors:

- 2002: The localized title for en-gb is missing or empty. Update your
  file and then try again.
- 2002: The localized title for en-us is
  missing or empty. Update your file and then try again.
- 2002: The
  localized title for de-DE is missing or empty. Update your file and
  then try again.
- 2002: The localized title for de-de is missing or
  empty. Update your file and then try again.
- 2000: Can’t open resource file: AppResLib.

Do you have any problems with localizate app title? Do everyone know, what I made wrong?
I´m happy for every info.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you move the *.mui to the resource folder? and do you have .xlf files?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `AppTitle` entry may be missing in `AppResLib.rc` file? Or `Caption` property value is not set?

One other thing to note, is that you need to update your title property in `WMAppManifest.xml` to something like

```
Title="@AppResLib.dll,-100"
```

and

```
<Title>@AppResLib.dll,-101</Title>
```

, where 100 and 101 are the values you use in `AppResLib.rc`.